# Why doesn't {$ifopt FINITEFLOAT ON} compile?

Tags: delphi, syntax-error, delphi-2006, compiler-options

I have the construct:

```
{$ifopt FINITEFLOAT ON}
  {$message 'FINITEFLOAT option ON' }
{$else }
  {$message 'FINITEFLOAT option OFF' }
{$endif }
```

in my source and it won't compile!  It's got to be something stupid.  The error is:

E1030 Invalid compiler directive: '$IFOPT'

at the first line, but it is the FINITEFLOAT it's complaining about.  You don't seem to be able to specify anything except the single letter directives like R+ etc as the argument of IFOPT.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are totally correct AFAICT. I don't use `$IFOPT` often but everytime I *do* this behaviour annoys me. I have no idea why this is implemented this way.

**Edit:** There's a [Quality Central ticket for this](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221122232/qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=43578).

**Edit:** There's a [Quality Portal ticket for this](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33621).

Comment: Just found this:  "http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/X1030_Invalid_compiler_directive_-_'%25s'_(Delphi)"  (quoted URL as S/O doesn't parse the URL properly if it ends in a ")").  And I see the QC.  Unbelievable.  So I can't report the state of a compiler option that doesn't have an abbreviated form?

Comment: Aside.  Found my posting in a google search less than 15 minutes after submitting it.  Now that's quick.

Answer (score 1):

True, you cant :( Thats because IFOPT considered as backward compatibility feature and doesnt work with any extended directives. eg: `{$A2}` can be set, but not retrieved back